# Magento - remove + (plus sign) from Magento navigation menu

Tags: php, css, magento

I need to remove the "+" from a single menu item in my Magento navigation.

I've poked around the core and theme files, and didn't find anything I was comfortable with removing. Also, [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263805/) post and [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/65535/) post seemed relevant, but not directly related to my issue with the navigation menu(or topmenu?). Both posts had me in the site's core files which seemed odd. Can anyone shed some light on this? Where should I be looking to remove that pesky "+"?

[live site](http://iikonee.com)

Comment: Right click on the plus, select *"Inspect Element"*, see where it comes from, fix it. That's about the only useful thing anyone can say about this without a live sample of what you're referring to.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Oh, yep. Forgot the site link. Please see my original question for the live site link. (Inspect Element indicates that the plus sign is at womens.html, which I was also unable to locate.)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's in the hard HTML output, you can only easily remove it with some custom CSS, for example:

```
.vertnav .opener {
    display:none;
}
```

Adding this rule to your theme's CSS will make it go away permanently, without editing any core files.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but adding that code showed no changes to the site? (Browser cache was cleared prior to loading.)

Comment: Works fine when I enter it in debug tools in the browser? Depending on where you inserted it in the template code, it might be overwritten by a later or more specific CSS rule. In that case, use `display:none !important;` to be sure.

Comment: Also, I don't see it at all on your live site, so either you didn't add it correctly there yet or made another mistake somewhere.

Comment: I added via FTP to - /skin/frontend/ultimo/default/styles.css

This was really the only css file I found; sorry if I'm overlooking something, this is my first run with Magento.